# What is the lowest-degree function that passes through these points?

Tags: polynomials

I want to find a (preferably polynomial) function that passes through the following twelve points:

- $(1, 0)$
- $(2, 3)$
- $(3, 3)$
- $(4, 6)$
- $(5, 1)$
- $(6, 4)$
- $(7, 6)$
- $(8, 2)$
- $(9, 5)$
- $(10, 0)$
- $(11, 3)$
- $(12, 5)$

The values outside these points do not matter. Obviously, there are infinitely many functions that pass through all these points.

Given any one point and the two zeroes, I can calculate a quadratic function to pass through them. For example, the function that passes through $(0, 1)$, $(0, 10)$, and $(6, 4)$ is found with

$$
\begin{align}
c(6 - 1)(6 - 10) &= 4\\
(5)(-4)c &= 4\\
c &= -\frac{1}{5}\\
f(x) &= -\frac{1}{5}(x - 1)(x - 10)
\end{align}
$$

But I have no idea how to calculate this for the multiple points I need.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: See Lagrange Interpolation:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial

Comment: Additionally, the Lagrange interpolation polynomial actually has degree 11 in this case, but not particularly "pretty" coefficients.

Comment: Finding the day of the week for the first day of the month, are we?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Good catch!

Comment: In view of Robert's observation you may want to enlarge the pool of polynomials to those having the prescribed values modulo seven.

Comment: @RobertIsrael These numbers can actually be used to find the day of the week for any Gregorian or Julian date, but yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of ways to collocate points through those points. Lagrange is one of them. I have calculated it for you in case you require the answer. Here it is in Horner form for quick computation.

$$y=-519+x \left(\frac{4798141}{3960}+x \left(-\frac{50014963}{50400}+x \left(\frac{34689413}{113400}+x \left(\frac{3930023}{120960} \right.\right.\right.\right.$$ $$+ \left.\left.\left.\left. x\left(-\frac{19645147}{362880}+x \left(\frac{1065259}{57600}+x\left(-\frac{586327}{172800} +x \left(\frac{3781}{10080}+x\left(-\frac{2269}{90720} \right.\right.\right.\right.\right.\right.\right.\right.\right.$$ $$\left. \left. \left. \left. \left. \left. \left. \left. \left. +x \left(\frac{1123}{1209600}-x\frac{589 }{39916800}\right) \right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

[image]

Comment: What tool did you use to put under Horner form ? I guess you did not do it by hand ! ;)

Comment: @jibe although it is possible to do it by hand it is much more accurate to let a program do it. I used Mathematica but I suppose Wolfram Alpha could do it just as well.

Comment: I didn't know Mathematica already had `HornerForm` and `InterpolatingPolynomial` : great !

Comment: A difference table could have done it too.

Answer (score 5):

There is a unique polynomial of degree at most $11$ which passes through these $12$ points.  If you denote your points by $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_{12},y_{12})$, this polynomial is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{12}y_k\frac{P_k}{Q_k}\ ,$$
where

- $P_k$ is the product of the factors $x-x_j$, where $j$ takes all values from $1$ to $12$ **except** k;
- $Q_k$ is the product of the numbers $x_k-x_j$, where $j$ takes all values from $1$ to $12$ **except** k.

If you are lucky, this will actually turn out to have a fairly small degree.  If you are not lucky, it won't ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use Lagrange interpolation: Idea is as follows:
Suppose you want your function to pass through the following distinct points: $(a,A), (b,B)$ and $(c,C)$ (note: $a \neq b \neq c$) then we first construct the polynomials
$$L_1(x)=\frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}$$
Observe that $L_1(c)=L_1(b)=0$ and $L_1(a)=1$.
Likewise construct $L_2(x)$ and $L_3(x)$. Once you have this then define
$$f(x)=AL_1(x)+BL_2(x)+CL_3(x).$$

Comment: Not quite right. It does guarantee to give the lowest degree polynomial. It does not guarantee to give a polynomial of degree $N-1$ (the degree will be at most $N-1$ but could be lower).

Comment: you are right my mistake. I have edited it.